# Factorising numbers (~200 digits) methods.

Tags: prime-factorization, python

are there any mathematical methods used to factorize huge integers(around 200 digits)? I'm doing that in Python, by the way. Also, if I ever get around a proper algorithm to do it, how much time should I expect it to run? Would i need a lot of workforce?

Comment: Algebraic number sieve.

Comment: [Read this...](https://www.mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?t=11009)

Comment: Python is not a good choice for factorizations of large numbers. I suggest to download yafu or perhaps msieve. $200$ digits will in general take very, very long, but you can of course be lucky to find the factors much faster. For small factors, ECM is the best method.